# Python Pandas: pass dataframe from one import lib to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can i pass a dataframe from another library call like this?
I want to be able to print(df1 from pytyhon.test.py... But the read_csv that creates the data frame is
from the import my_functions lib.. (i created to do some specific things..)
This just an easier example to show what I want to do.. my actual issue is more complex...

Example:
pythontest.py:

```
import my_functions
print(df1)  # how can I print this here??? if the dataframe was created in my_functions???
```

my_functions.py:

```
import pandas as pd
global df1
df1 = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to use `global`. When you import `my_functions` from `pythontest.py`, `df1` is already in the same scope.

To access it, you would refer to it as `my_functions.df1`, however. Alternatively, you can import elements from `my_functions` explicitly:

```py
from my_functions import df1
```

or you can import everything:

```py
from my_functions import *
```

To understand the different behaviours I would recommend you read [the documentation on python modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!  excellently explained and appreciate the document.!  Thanks again! Got it working correctly!  was trying to google and read up on it.. but was stuck , you answer was simple and perfect!